# Does a breath weapon count as a weapon attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonborn

Certain features such as the Bard college of Swords Blade Flourish require you to hit a creature with a weapon attack.

> Whenever you take the Attack action on your turn, [...], and if a weapon attack that you make as part of this action hits a creature, you can use one of the following Blade Flourish options of your choice. You can use only one Blade Flourish option per turn.

For this purpose, does the Dragonborn's Breath *weapon* attack count?

> **Breath Weapon.** When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can replace one of your attacks with an exhalation of magical energy in a 30-foot line that is 5 feet wide. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw (DC = 8 + your Constitution modifier + your proficiency bonus). On a failed save, the creature takes 1d10 damage of the type associated with your Chromatic Ancestry. On a successful save, it takes half as much damage. [...]

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145491/what-is-the-difference-between-a-ranged-attack-and-a-ranged-weapon-attack

Comment: I've just spotted that these aren't the Players Handbook rules, but are from the Unearthed Arcana in 2021.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.