# What's the longest range attainable with a ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, ranged-attack

I'm looking to build a character as close to RAW geared around becoming a long ranged sniper who deals damage from the furthest safest distance. I've been looking at features from ranger/familiar that allow a PC to look through their companion's vision for line of sight, but is there a way to make actually attacking from this distance effective?

Constraints:

- Attack must be made with a weapon. The weapon can be effected by a spell or enchanted, if it's a class spell or feature, but the instrument should be some simple or martial weapon at it's base.
- Exclude any outside influence from other PCs or magic items that aren't inherent to the class.
- PC would be at level 6. It would be interesting to learn how the range/class optimization changes with an increase in level though.
- UA would be fine but I know it's trickier to balance multiclassing with.
- For effectiveness, the attack should be made without being at a disadvantage if possible.
- Any feats/spells, but excluding magic items.

Comment: Related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150698/what-is-eldritch-blasts-maximum-range

Comment: **Heavily related:** [What is the maximum distance you can cause damage from?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159462/35259) _(this link is to my answer specifically, since it's arguably more related than the rest of the Q&A, given that the **original** question that I answered was closer to this question... of course, my answer is effectively the same as [Someone_Evil's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159858/35259) below...)_

Answer (score 12):

## Longbow: 600 ft.

No, really. To my knowledge there is nothing which lets you increase the range of a longbow beyond 600 ft. (I would love to be proven wrong about that.)

You can take the Sharpshooter feat (PHB 170) which removes disadvantage on attacks in the 150-600 ft. range, but it does not extend it beyond that.
You can do this at first level with any class, by taking the Variant Human race option to choose the feat.

Answer (score 0):

#### Longbow:  1100 ft, but only starting at 11th level

To expand on @Someone_Evil's answer and address how this would scale with level, [Arcane Gate](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/arcane-gate), available via Sorcerer / Wizard / Warlock level 11 (emphasis mine) says

> Any creature **or object** entering the portal exits from the other portal as if the two were adjacent to each other; passing through a portal from the nonportal side has no effect.

Round 1, place portals 500 ft apart. Pray to your spoopy demon god thing that nobody cares about a giant shimmering portal

Round 2, fire away!  If you're Pact of the Blade, pick up Thirsting Blade for a second shot

Comment: *Arcane Gate* is not available to a 6th level caster.

Comment: @NautArch which is why I mentioned "level 11" and referenced the question's third bullet point, in which the OP said `It would be interesting to learn how the range/class optimization changes with an increase in level though`

Comment: Fun answer! Thanks for posting :) I don't believe this is very feasible in most circumstances but strictly speaking its definitely possible!

Comment: Unfortunately "The mist that fills each portal is opaque and blocks vision through it."  Which means you wouldn't be able to see your victim.